# How to pass multiple parameters (request + 2 another params)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a projet that sends SMS messages to our customers.

I'm trying to create a new row in my database with eloquent, and I am passing 3 parameters in my function.

TraitementController.php

```
public function send_sms_reply(Request $request, Client $client, $id)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate ([
            'expediteur' => 'Reponse',
            'texte' => 'required|string',
            'type' => 2,
            'conversation_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'client_id' => $client->id,
            'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'statut' => 0,
        ]);

        $sms_cree = Sms::create($validatedData);

[...]

}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('envoyer/sms', 'TraitementController@send_sms_reply')->name('traitements.send_sms_reply');
```

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('traitements.send_sms_reply', $conversation->client, Auth::user()->id) }}">
@csrf
@method('POST')
    <select class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <option value="">Choix modèle de réponse</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="text" required>GRDF Bonjour</textarea>
    <input id="conversation_id" name="conversation_id" type="text" value="{{ $conversation->id }}" style="display:none">
    <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" style="display:none">
    <i>Retour pas encore traité</i>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Répondre</button>
</form>
```

I finally get this error when I'm clicking the submit button.

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TraitementController::send_sms_reply(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error ?

Comment: "_Do you know why I'm getting this error ?_" Yes, because you are only passing 2 arguments to the function and it expects 3.

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing `Auth::user()->id` in form parameter? though you can get it in controller directly. in your controller directly you can access Auth::id();

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I know, but normally when I'm using the Request parameter, I don't need to pass any

Comment: @DilipHirapara Thank you, did'nt know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route like below so it can accept params that are required for `send_sms_reply` function

```
Route::post('envoyer/sms/{client}/{id}', 'TraitementController@send_sms_reply')->name('traitements.send_sms_reply');
```

to pass multiple params to route you can do something like this in your form

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('traitements.send_sms_reply', ['client' => $conversation->client, 'id' => Auth::user()->id)] }}">
@csrf
/* Your code */
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I already tried that, and I got `array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given`

Comment: `$conversation->client` should be an object make sure it is object try `dd ($client)`

Comment: It is, I tried this and dd($client->id) ad it's returning the id of the client

Comment: what is the output of `$conversation->client`

Comment: Route model binding is probably what you want to do with the client parameter. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: can you post output here?

Comment: @SalmanZafar `Client {#326 ▼
  #fillable: array:8 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "clients"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}`

Comment: @Petoux can you post final url that should be something like this `envoyer/sms/2/1`?

Comment: @SalmanZafar I got the Auth user id directly in the controller, so I only need the {client} parameter, I can use $client variable in the controller. The url looks like : http://localhost:8000/messages/envoyer/sms/1

Comment: @Petoux have you updated your route and form? as you are using `Auth::id()` in your controller

Comment: @SalmanZafar of course : `Route::post('envoyer/sms/{client}', 'TraitementController@send_sms_reply')->name('traitements.send_sms_reply');`
`public function send_sms_reply(Request $request, Client $client)`

Comment: and so now your form should look like this `<form method="post" action="{{ route('traitements.send_sms_reply', $conversation->client}}"> @csrf </form>`

Comment: @SalmanZafar exactly `<form method="post" action="{{ route('traitements.send_sms_reply', $conversation->client) }}">`

Comment: @SalmanZafar When I'm sending the form I get this `array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given`

Comment: @Petoux you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733568/laravel-5-8-says-array-map-expected-parameter-2-to-be-an-array-int-given as  this is not a issue of routing